# How can I create a Javascript function to manage (Bootstrap) dropdown menu clicks instead of creating a large number of listeners?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, bootstrap-4

My project has a large number of dropdown menus. My current scheme is to create jquery listeners for each control, however, it seems reasonable that a single function could accomplish the same task.
Please see the onlick event in the markup.

```
<div class="input-group">
   <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <button id="PrimaryPhoneType" class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Type</button>
      <div id="ddlPrimaryPhoneType" class="dropdown-menu" onclick="ManageDDlClicks('ddlPrimaryPhoneType','tbPriPhoneType')">
         <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Cell</a>
         <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Home</a>
         <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Work</a>
      </div>
   </div>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tbPriPhoneType" runat="server">
</div>
```

Current listener scheme:

```
  $('#<%=ddlPrimaryPhoneType.ClientID %> a').click(function () {
     $('#<%=tbPriPhoneType.ClientID %>').val($(this).html());
  });
```

Proposed new function:

```
function ManageDDlClicks(src, tgt) {
   let list = document.getElementById(src).getElementsByTagName('a');
   console.log(list);
   var selItem = list.???
   document.getElementById(tgt).value = selItem
}
```

Debugging & studying the contents of the "list", I see nothing in the nodes that point to which item was selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure if I'm understanding you correctly, but I would drop the onClick in the markup, and make an event handler that can handle all clicked events. If your markup remains consistent something like this could work:

```
$('.dropdown-menu a').click(function () {
  $(this).parents('.input-group-prepend').next().val($(this).text())
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/p03btj92/

There are certainly different ways of doing it though:

```
$('.dropdown-menu a').click(function () {
  $(this).parents('.input-group').find('input[type="text"]').val($(this).text())
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/af4ke57b/

Using id based selectors is going to require you to write code specifically for each element you want to interact with. The idea is to instead use the `$(this)` selector, in conjunction with reusable classes.

From there you can use [DOM Traversal Methods](https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) to find the element you would like to modify. In this case [parents](https://api.jquery.com/parents/), [next](https://api.jquery.com/next/), and [find](https://api.jquery.com/find/) were used.

Comment: So simple. Thanks a bunch.